# What is the strongest link made in the philosophical literature between privacy and civil liberties?

Tags: society, marxism, self, philosophy-of-technology, economics

What is the strongest link made in the philosophical literature between privacy and civil liberties? In particular, an analysis which eschews 'democracy', or separates out democracy from 'civil society'.

I tend to agree with the recent, belated, [press](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/jan/20/shoshana-zuboff-age-of-surveillance-capitalism-google-facebook) on '[surveillance capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surveillance_capitalism)', that we are entering a new phase of capitalism as we did with general motors and '[mass production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_production)'.

On the one hand, it could end up less physically demeaning than mass production lines, but, on the other, the potential for the state and economy to not just suppress and repress dissent but actively mold its citizens' experiences according to demand is vast. Any Marxist, or Situationist, analysis, in particular, would be especially welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91662/discussion-on-question-by-another-name-what-is-the-strongest-link-made-in-the-ph).